# getting data from server in xml format

Tags: php

I am trying to call a web service through php . I am sending an XML request for which I am supposed to get back an Xml response.  But I as response I am getting only the data without the xml tags. I want it in proper xml format. I also have the wsdl file of the website. If anyone can advise what to do it will be of real help. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
<?php  
$soapUrl=some url';
$xml_post_string='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext" xmlns:urn="urn:ebx-schemas:dataservices_1.0">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sec:Security>
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>Some Value</Username>
            <Password>Some Value</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
      </sec:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:select_ProductDetail>
         <branch>Product</branch>
         <instance>Product</instance>
         <viewPublication>List Name</viewPublication>
      </urn:select_ProductDetail>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';




   $headers = array( 
   "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8", 
   "Accept: gzip,deflate", 
   "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
   "Pragma: no-cache", 
   "SOAPAction: \"select\"", 
    "Host: Host name",
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",       
   "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string), 
   ); 

   // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $soapUrl);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 500);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 12);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   $ss = curl_getinfo($ch);
   $response = curl_exec($ch); 
   print_r($response);
   exit;
   curl_close($ch);   
   ?>
```

Comment: are you viewing it in BROWSER, I meant your result/Output ?

Comment: use my below code it will solve your issue

Comment: @CodingAnt yes I am viewing the result in browser.

Comment: @Ricky thanks for your fast reply and time  but your code is not solving my problem . I am  getting the dteh following output using your code :  SimpleXMLElement Object ( )  :( Thanks any way

Comment: @sagariray have you print $response with my code you must print it and then exit; after that view page source you will see the xml format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your codes to below, for viewing it in **BROWSERS**

```
   $ss = curl_getinfo($ch);
   $response = curl_exec($ch); 
   echo '<pre>';
   echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($response, true));
   echo '</pre>';
   #print_r($response);
   exit;
   curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are not getting output in xml format because output is getting concatenated with header of curl to avoid so use below code**

**// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth**

```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $soapUrl);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 500);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 12);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   $ss = curl_getinfo($ch);
   //$response will give you xml format code
   $response = curl_exec($ch); 
   //$xml will create array from that xml format code
   $xml=simplexml_load_string($response);
   print_r($xml);
   exit;
   curl_close($ch);
```